# How to handle exceptions in wcf service call back

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, exception

I am trying to log my exceptions with AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += AppDomainUnhandledException;
public static void AppDomainUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
        HandleException(e.ExceptionObject as Exception);
}
```

When I get an exception in the server I will get the fault in the client at debug time but the event hooked to AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException will never be fired.

Server:

```
[ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true)]
public class Service : IService
{        

    public string GetError()
    {
       throw new ApplicationException();
    }
}
```

Client:

```
public void GetError()
{
   this.service.BeginGetError(OnGetErrorCompleted, null);
}

public void OnGetErrorCompleted(IAsyncResult result)
{ 
    var value = this.service.EndGetError(result);
}
```

This doesn't work UNLESS I use Distpacher.BeginInvoke..

```
public void OnGetErrorCompleted(IAsyncResult result)
{
    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
    {
        var value = this.service.EndGetError(result);
    }));           
}
```

Somebody knows why?? 
I thought AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException would be fired in case of an exception in ANY thread! :S

Answer (score 0):

A better solution is to use something like [IErrorHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler.aspx) and throw FaultExceptions. Decorate your operations to throw FaultExceptions using the [FaultContract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752208.aspx) attribute. Now you can catch specific FaultExceptions at the client. You should not expose exceptions on the server to the client.

Comment: I'm already converting Exceptions to Faults in the server with [ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true)]. I also tried with Entreprise library exception to fault conversion and using FaultContracts as you said. So I am not getting exceptions on the client, but faults.

Comment: You're still exposing your server exceptions to your client. How is your client supposed to handle something that happened on the server? Don't use `IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults` but use something like `IErrorHandler` to provide faults.